# Error in installing packages in pop os

Tags: packaging, pop-os

Not able to load packages in Eddy.

Getting this following error:

```
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_InRelease (1)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package information is corrupted, try rebuilding the cache:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```

Comment: It worked thanks for your help :)